# iOS - disable right or left swipe for UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios11, swipe

I have implemented iOS 11 `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` and `leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` for my UITableViewCell. I'm using `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` to disable the row, and `leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` to undo the disable of the row. I've tried to use `canEditRowAt`, but this disables editing of the entire row. Is there a way to disable only one of the swipe actions instead of disabling the entire row from editing?

I want to disable the undo swipe action if I already swiped to undo, but enable the cancel swipe action. I also want to disable the cancel swipe action if I already swiped to cancel, but enable the undo swipe action.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to return the empty array of actions in `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` method to disable one sided action.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

   let swipeAction = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [])

   return swipeAction
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Returning nil is sufficient to prevent the swipe action.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

   return nil
}
```